# What are my options for syncing a folder between a Mac and a PC?

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization

Suppose I have 2 computers attached to the wireless network in my house, one a Mac and one a PC.  Suppose I want to continuously sync a folder on the Mac with a folder on the PC.  What options do I have?

My first thought would be to use something like Dropbox, but in this case I don't want the files to leave my network and go to the cloud.

Edit: NAS not available here, nor is an external drive.  Just the 2 computers.

Comment: This isn't a software solution, but a great way to share files could be from a separate drive. Something like Apple's [Time Capsule](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD032/time-capsule-2tb) would work.

Comment: BestBuySync 2013 claims to be able to do what I want, but it's PC only and requires the business license version for $78.  Ow!

Comment: ViceVersa PRO makes the same claims.  Still PC only.  $60.

Comment: Allway Sync is another PC choice, free for limited home use, $20 for full version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I have found is Cubby.  It's a Dropbox competitor, but it has a feature known as DirectSync that allows you to sync one or more folders across computers (Mac or PC) without uploading them to Cubby's cloud.

The downside?  From Cubby's FAQ: "Cubby always sets up direct UDP connections between clients unless your firewall or NAT configuration prevents it from doing so, in which case data is relayed through our data centers using a TCP based, E2E secure SSL tunnel."  IOW, it might run through their servers, which means it's not a perfect solution for my situation.  Still, it's close.

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox does have an option called **LAN sync**, which syncs files between computers on a LAN directly. However this still also syncs them to the cloud, it just saves you some internet bandwidth.

As @woz suggested, a file share on either computer or a NAS (including Time Capsule) would do the job. You could also run [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) from a cronjob, or use [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/mac), which has a neat GUI for that.

Comment: Dropbox DOES have an option called LAN sync, but that is just to preserve bandwidth. It still uploads everything to the Dropbox servers, but it means that if there is another computer on the same network it doesn't have to download it from the net.